# Escape ampersand sign in javascript in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, escaping

I have asp page which retrieves javascript code from code behind file. The code consists of companyName which sometimes have '&' sign. This javascript codeis used during onclick event of a link in the asp page. However it looks like whenever there is a comapnyName with '&' sign, it cuts of the string value after the '&' sign.

```
Code Behind:
    <sc:Link runat="server" Field="EmployeeLink" Item='<%# Eval("Item") %>' onclick='<%# Eval("OnClickJs") %>'>

ASP file:
    OnClickJS =  "var d=d_gi('" + Sitecore.Context.Item["ID"] + "');d.tl(this,'d','Page " + "|" +companyName +");";
```

> When companyName is 'John Doe' => the link has 'John Doe' in link url
>
> When companyName is 'John & Doe' => the link only has 'John' in link
>   url

I tried escaping ampersand sign using '\', '&' 'amp;' so far.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Sanjeev

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode for this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx

```
OnClickJS =  HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode("var d=d_gi('" + Sitecore.Context.Item["ID"] + "');d.tl(this,'d','Page " + "|" +companyName +")");
```